# Winsorizing same variable for different datasets

Tags: r

I am new to programming in R and am testing a trading strategy.

I have 20 different datasets (data1999, data2000, ... , data2018) which all have the same variables.

Right now I am facing some problems with writing for loops. For example, I want to Winsorize a variable for each year in a for loop. As an illustration, I copied the code below:

```
files <- c(data1999, data2000,data2001)
for(i in 1: length(files)) {
  eval(parse(text=files[i]))['K/BW'] <- 
    Winsorize(eval(parse(text=files[i]))['K/BW'],  minval = NULL, maxval = NULL, na.rm= TRUE, probs = c(0.05,0.95))
}
```

I have tried different things but I can't seem to manage to build a good for loop for this. Could anybody help me?

Thanks in advance.
Pieter

Answer (score 0):

First I’ll create some random data sets so that this example can be
reproduced. I will use the `replicate` function to generate 20
`data.frames` in a list

```r
set.seed(60656731)

files <-
  replicate(n = 20L,
            {data.frame("Var1" = rnorm(1000), "Var2" = runif(1000), "Var3" = rexp(1000))},
            simplify = FALSE)
```

I am assuming you are using the `Winsorize` function from the
[DescTools](https://cran.r-project.org/package=DescTools) package.

```r
library(DescTools)
```

Use `lapply`, i.e., list apply, to apply the `Winsorize` function to the data
sets. The below creates a new set of `data.frame`s where `Var1` of the data
sets have been winsorized.

```r
files_winsorized <- lapply(files, function(x) {x$Var1 <- Winsorize(x$Var1); x})
```

A quick look at one of the results:

```r
par(mfrow = c(2, 1))
hist(files[[1]]$Var1)
hist(files_winsorized[[1]]$Var1)
```

[image]

```r
summary(files[[1]]$Var1)
#>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#> -2.884652 -0.722562 -0.001219 -0.021644  0.611927  3.060625
summary(files_winsorized[[1]]$Var1)
#>      Min.   1st Qu.    Median      Mean   3rd Qu.      Max. 
#> -1.592469 -0.722562 -0.001219 -0.021551  0.611927  1.636466
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>